# Convert regular expression into re2 that works in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I would like to use a regular expression that works otherwise, but it does not work in Google Sheets.

Google Sheets requires [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt) expressions and I don't know how to format this properly.
(I've read lots of questions here on StackOverflow already but unfortunately I am stuck.)

I would like to convert the following expression:

```
\w++\-?+\w*+\.\w++\/
```

The expression is intended to do the following.
Extract the domain names from a given URL. For example:

```
from: https://www.tag24.de/dresden/ 
get: tag24.de/

from: https://de.nachrichten.yahoo.com/wohnen-hamburg-bezirk-f
get: yahoo.com/

from: https://www.hitradio-rtl.de/beitrag/hier-leben
get: hitradio-rtl.de/
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can remove the additional `+` signs as re2 does not support possessive quantifiers `\w+-?\w*\.\w+/`

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\w+(?:-\w+)?\.\w+(?:/|$)")`? Or even `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\w[\w-]*\.\w+(?:/|$)")`?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew - Both solutions work and solve the use case!

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird. Your solution works with my code by adopting it to re2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can post it before it disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the possessive quantifiers are [not supported in RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt):

> ```
> Possessive repetitions:
> x*+   zero or more «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> x++   one or more «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> x?+   zero or one «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> x{n,m}+   «n» or ... or «m» «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> x{n,}+    «n» or more «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> x{n}+ exactly «n» «x», possessive NOT SUPPORTED
> ```

You can use

```sql
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\w+(?:-\w+)?\.\w+(?:/|$)")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\w[\w-]*\.\w+(?:/|$)")
```

In case you want to exclude the final `/`, use a capturing group:

```sql
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\w+(?:-\w+)?\.\w+)(?:/|$)")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\w[\w-]*\.\w+)(?:/|$)")
```

*Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:-\w+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `-` and one or more word chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:/|$)` - either a `/` or end of string.
- `\w[\w-]*` - one word char and then zero or more word or hyphen chars (that is good if you do not carehow many hyphens there can be after the first word char, or if there can be several consecutive hyphens).

When a capturing group is used in the regex, only its contents is returned by `REGEXEXTRACT`.

See a Google Sheets demo:

[image]